Backup Android Phone to PC
I would like to backup all the data on my phone. I saw that the Google Drive backup of my phone shown below, only encompases about 200MB. But my phone storage is 64 GB. From that about 10GB are WhatsApp messages, that are backed up to google drive, but in a propriatary file format. When the smartphone storage is opened in a file explorer only a subset of the files in "Internal Storage" are shown, which are themselves only a fraction of the files located on the smartphone, eg. WhatsApp media.
My question should be simple, but seems suprisingly hard to answer:
How can I back up as much of the data from my phone as possible?
I use a  Google Pixel 4 and Arch Linux

